# Get a list of values from SQL Server and pass it to For Each activity in Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: foreach, azure-data-factory

I have a list of document numbers stored in a table in SQL Server database.

I want to pass these values to "For Each" activity in ADF.

I tried lookup activity and stored procedure activity but I'm unable to pass it to "For Each" activity as it expects an array.

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried?

Comment: Lookup activity which calls the stored procedure which returns Document Numbers. I passed the output of this activity to For Each activity. 
This gives me an error saying it cannot accept objects

Comment: Then I replaced the lookup activity to Stored Procedure which returns a comma separated string (e.g. SO0033342, SO0033343, SO0033344)

Created an array variable

Set this variable with the output of the above stored procedure activity. Set Variable activity failed this time as it expects an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retrieved the `docNumber` column number using lookup activity with below query:

```
select docNumber from docs
```

The values fetched successfully. I pass those values into foreach activity with below dynamic expression:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output
```

Added setvariable activity in foreach activiy with below expression:

```
@string(item().docNumber)
```

When I execute the pipeline, I got the same error:

[image]

I changed the foreach activity item expression as mentioned below:

```
  @activity('Lookup1').output.value
```

[image]

And again, I executed the pipeline, it executed successfully without any error:

[image]